# Notices are render inside sub-menu's content

Tags: sub-menu, notices

I develop a plugin but I've got a problem when I render sub-menus (added with the hook admin_menu). At the moment of the callback, I render the content with the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php $this->render(); ?>
</div>
```

But I don't know why they are render inside the same content (see attachment).
[image]
I'm using PHP/MySQL 7.4.2 with theme Sydney Pro in localhost

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is that notice rendered - with an admin_notice hook? Can you also check if it's actually in the wrong place in the HTML or whether it's been moved into the wrong place by CSS / styles?

Comment: @Rup thanks for you're answer.
It's a problem too, I never call the hook admin_notice.
And in the HTML, the notice have a wrong place too

Comment: admin_notice is called automatically by the WordPress, and it's usually where notices like this are generated. I don't know Elementor: I'd start by looking through the plugin code to work out how it's rendering this error message, and then you can work out how that is ending up in the middle of your menu.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to look at their code